# Visual Studio Solution Explorer - Different icons observed for Asset files

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, assets

I added a `3mf` file to a UWP sample project in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition (name: pyramid.3mf).  I noticed that a similar file (name: box.3mf) that was already included in the sample has a little blue arrow over its icon, whereas the file I added does not, as shown below:

[image]

In the Properties Window (F4), both files are set as `Build Action: Content, Copy to Output Directory: Copy always`.  The new file works fine and displays correctly, but curiously, the Full Path for the new file shows the target (copied to) folder, not the original folder where I added the file from.

Also, `File Name` field for the old file (box.3mf) is greyed out, while the `File Name` for the new file (pyramid.3mf) is not greyed out.

[image]
[image]

What do the differences in the icons signify, and how can I add the new file so that it matches the old one in terms of properties? (I.e. so that the path name is the folder where I added the file from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out the little blue arrow indicates that the file was added as a link.  Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100)), I deleted the pyramid.3mf and re-added it into the project using the "Add As Link" option (Solution Explorer → Add → Existing Item…):

[image]

The file now shows up with the proper icon:

[image]